# Lifeary - Creating folders and sub folders under Web Content using portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am working on reading excel data in portlet and putting it under **Web Content** and sorting them into different folders and subfolders.

All I found is **creating files and folders under the Documents and Media library but not under the Web Content**

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029045451-Creating-Files-Folders-and-Shortcuts
https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028725672-Creating-Folders

Follow these steps to create a folder with the `DLAppService` method `addFolder`:

Get a reference to `DLAppService`:

```
@Reference
private DLAppService _dlAppService;
```

Get the data needed to populate the `addFolder` method’s arguments. Since it’s common to create a folder with data submitted by the end user, you can extract the data from the request. This example does so via `javax.portlet.ActionRequest` and `ParamUtil`:

```
long repositoryId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "repositoryId");
long parentFolderId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "parentFolderId");
String name = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "name");
String description = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "description");

ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(
            DLFolder.class.getName(), actionRequest);
```

Call the service reference’s addFolder method with the data from the previous step:

```
Folder folder = _dlAppService.addFolder(
                        repositoryId, parentFolderId, name, description, 
                        serviceContext);
```

Please let me know or guide me on how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to store excel file or to read excel file and create web content using the data?

Comment: @DanieleBaggio, It is to read excel file and create web content using the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Document Library*, you can upload and store *documents*.

Under *Web Content*, you can create and store *web content articles*.

You sound like you want to store documents (e.g. excel files) under Web Content, and that's not what those folders are being built for. Note that this is not a file system, but those are distinct ways to organize the different types of content.

So, the way to solve this problem is to go back to the requirements, and find a working technical solution for the underlying business problem.

Any folder you create through an API with the `DL` prefix will appear under the Document Library. Any folder you create through an API starting with a `Journal` prefix will appear under Web Content. There simply is no overlap.